# Variable bit shift

Tags: assembly, x86, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

I'm looking to shift a register bits n times to the left specified with another register. For example, something like this

```
shl    eax, ebx
```

The only problem being is that the 2nd operand cannot be a register, it has to be an immediate value. How would I be able to shift a register by a value not known at assemble-time?

Comment: Are you writing inline assembly in C/C++ ?

Comment: No, otherwise I would've just used the shift operators.

Comment: You should read the instruction set reference.

Answer (score 18):

In x86 you can specify a shift count in register `cl`. So `shl eax, cl` is valid.

```
mov   ecx, ebx
shl   eax, cl
```

Note that you can only use the `cl` register, not `eax` or any other register.

Also, shift counts greater than 31 are performed modulo 32.  (Not modulo the operand-size, so narrow shifts like `shl ax, 20` *can* shift all the bits out and leave the destination zero.  64-bit shifts mask the count with `& 63`, though, so `shl rax, 32` (or with 32 in cl) is possible.  See [Intel's manual entry for `shl`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/SAL:SAR:SHL:SHR.html)).

---

The BMI2 instruction set extension supports [shifts with the count in any register](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/SARX:SHLX:SHRX.html), and which don't update EFLAGS, so they're more efficient for variable counts:

```
; if BMI2 is supported
shlx   edx, eax, ebx     ; edx = eax << (ebx&31)
```

It's only available on some Haswell+ CPUs, and Excavator / Ryzen CPUs, so you can't use it in fully portable code.